# Jenkins pipeline run gradle tasks within sshagent

Tags: jenkins, gradle, ssh

I'm creating a jenkins pipeline which utilizes a build.gradle script to build the project. 
One of the first things gradle does is check out some git repos, I need to run this with ssh, so I thought I could wrap the code in sshagent like this:

```
sshagent(['c6f7cd1b-9bb3-4b33-9db0-cbd1f62cd0ba']){
    sh 'git clone git@Repo.git'
}
```

the Id is mapped to a global jenkins credential with the private key in it, I also use it in another pipeline to tag a repo and push it to master, using the same credentialId. 
However I get following output when trying to run the pipeline:

```
FATAL: [ssh-agent] Could not find specified credentials
```

I have no idea why I get this, when I'm using a copy paste from the other pipeline.  
Anyone who can point me towards the right direction? 
Thx